# Fetching "id" from a view and pass to another view in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new in CodeIgniter. I'm having a problem fetching "id" from "project view" then i will pass it to another view which a call "project details view". 
I've tried using ampersand (&) in URL and i guess that does not work in CodeIgniter.

Here are my codes:

In my controller:

```
   

    public function project(){
        $data["title"] = "CodeIgniter Projects";
        $this->load->model("projects_model");
        $data["result"] = $this->projects_model->getProjects();
        $this->load->view("project", $data);    
    }

    public function project_details($project_id){
        $this->load->model("projects_model");
        $data["result"] = $this->projects_model->getProjectDetails($project_id);
            $this->load->view("project_details", $data);

    }
```

for my model

```
    function getProjects(){
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM projects");    

            return $query->result();
    }

    function getProjectDetails($project_id){
            $this->db->where('project_id', $project_id);    
            $query = $this->db->get('projects');
    }
```

in my view i only use `< a href="controller/project_details">< / a>` to call the project details view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass anything to controller from a view as a uri_segment. The general syntax is,

```
Controller/function/parameter
```

Here, in your case

```
controller/project_details/<?php echo $project_id; ?>
```